# SAS scaproc and %include

Tags: sas

Is there a way to profile a large job which calls multiple sources using `%include` with `proc scaproc`?

Running

```
proc scaproc; record 'out.txt'; run;
%include "job_part_1.sas";
%include "job_part_2.sas";
proc scaproc; write; run;
```

Gives the correct /* JOBSPLIT: ... */ meta-info but does not show the source code after a data step / proc sql / some other procedure.

Comment: If you are running batch you will need to look at the .log as well.  If interactive, you can use `PROC PRINTTO` to redirect the log, or use the `-altlog` startup option to record the log.  You can use options such as `FULLSTIMER MPRINT MLOGIC SYMBOLGEN MTRACE` to get very detailed logs.  Regardless, there is no one-click way to align log lines with scaproc output in a complex macro based solution framework.

Comment: I was really hoping the /source2 option would work here but unfortunately it doesn't.